# bootstrap 4 items next to each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align few items in bootstrap next to each other. More specifically i have image and text and i want to be in the order below with vertical and horizontal alignment nice and tidied up, with as much as less code.

```
+----------------+-----------------------------+
| centered image |  here is some centered text |
+----------------+-----------------------------+
| centered image |  here is some centered text |
+----------------+-----------------------------+
| centered image |  here is some centered text |
+----------------+-----------------------------+
```

Anyway i believe that there is a better way than the way i'm doing it.
This is what i've done so far.

One last thing, it would be nice if the collapse of the columns was only for mobile devices (in low resolution), but it's not a big deal in the end.

```html
<div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="margin: 110px 0px 0px 0px"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <img src="./images/1.png" height="150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9" style="padding: 40px;">
        <p>This is my super super super super dummy dummy text text text text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
      <div class="col-xs-3" style="padding: 30px 0px 0px 0px">
        <img src="./images/2.png" height="150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;">
        <div style="width:500px;">
          <p>This is my super super super super dummy dummy text text text text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px">
      <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px">
        <img src="./images/Change.png" height="150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9" style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 40px;">
        <div style="width:500px;">
          <p>
            This is my super super super super dummy dummy text text text text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have not used bootstrap in a long time, but seems like `col-xs-*` has been replaced with `col-*` in bootstrap4

Answer (score 0):

Note: I removed the parent div with col-8 with text-align left.

To center the columns vertically within the row, add `align-items-center` to the `row` div. To center a column horizontally and vertically within it's section of the row, add the class `align-self-center` to the `col-sm-*` div.

If you want the columns to collapse on mobile devices (extra small), you need to use the `col-sm-*` classes, which means that they will take up n number of columns on devices that are small or larger, and therefor will take up 100% of the space on extra small devices (standard phones, <576px wide).

Also Nodir Rashidov is correct, Bootstrap 4 has replaced Bootstrap 3's `col-xs-*` classes with `col-*` given that it is the lowest breakpoint and therefor the default for the smallest screen.

Bootstrap 4 also has utility classes for padding and margin, so you don't need to add those as inline styles: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/

You could also center the `img` and `p` tags in your column divs using the `m-auto` class (margin-auto).

For this type of layout (img aligned with text on the left) you could also try using the Bootstrap 4 Media object: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/media-object/ (check out the 'Center-aligned' example)

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome! Welcome!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-sm-3 align-self-center">
        <img src="./images/1.png" height="150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 align-self-center">
        <p>This is my super super super super dummy dummy text text text text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-sm-3 align-self-center">
        <img src="./images/2.png" height="150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 align-self-center">
          <p>This is my super super super super dummy dummy text text text text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-sm-3 align-self-center">
        <img src="./images/Change.png" height="150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 align-self-center">
          <p>This is my super super super super dummy dummy text text text text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```